# sound recorder problem ubuntu 10.10 Intel D945GCL

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, audio, skype, ubuntu-10.10

I've installed ubuntu 10.10 on my Intel D945GCL Mother board,
I'm not able to use my microphone - I've tested with front and back mike JACKs..

My Hardware selection is: `Analog Stereo Duplex`
Sound Preferences Input Selection: `Internal Audio Analog Stereo`

Answer (score 0):

make sure it isn't muted on the input tab and turn up the volume.  I haven't had a sigmatel fail on me before short of stupid power surges or something of that kind.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution - sharing here too

append following line to your `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file

`options snd-hda-intel model=3stack`

and reboot your machine